# PMO/Scrum Master visibility and contribution (upping the profile of the team)

Tags: team-management, project-team, team

I lead a small PMO team of 4 Project Managers/Scrum Masters. Given the nature of the business and the demands from senior management, we have adopted a hybrid approach to software development of Scrum and some traditional project tracking and reporting.

The PM/SMs facilitate and lead ceremonies as well as removing blockers. "Removing Blockers" can be expanded into many different unique and reoccurring issues so let your imagination run wild.

Given that the PM/SM team/function reports into the head of product the limelight is often on the product managers and senior devs. I want to increase the profile of my team to share all the good work they are doing, however, I'm unsure how I can do this

Does anyone have any tips or ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to make the PMs/SMs contribution more visible? What's the problem you are trying to solve? Are there any issues or just want to give credit where credit is due?

Answer (score 2):

If you want more visibility then you need to toot your horn louder.

Specifically, send out a periodic status report that begins with all the fantastic work you've done since the last update.

In your case, it would include a lot of unblocking. You can include a brief explanation of the severity of the blockage and the difficulty in removing it and the skills your team used to unblock it swiftly and efficiently.

The rest of the update will include upcoming work and forward-looking measures you're putting in place to prevent repeat blockages.

Don't over-dramatize, but make sure it's easy and fun to read.

Add a catchy title and people will look forward to receiving it.

Comment: Some helpful advice Danny, I've reviewed our reporting process with the program managers, however, we left out the key things you have mentioned. ie the blocker we have managed. Do you have any sources of reporting templates online you can recommend?

Comment: @Breezecom - I've never looked; I always write my reports from scratch so that they remain interesting. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the best measure of a SM's success is that the team can manage without an SM. SM's don't manage people or projects and should not "lead" ceremonies - it's good practice for SMs not to attend all the daily standups for example, just to make sure they happen. So I suggest the best thing is to raise the profile of the whole Scrum team rather than emphasising the role that one particular team member plays.